# What is the purpose of this wooden rectangular arch shaped construct in Siberia?

Tags: russia, identify-this

Between the Khobeyu/Хобею and Naroda/Народа valleys, in the Beryozovsky District, Khanty-Mansi Autonomous Okrug, Russia, about 75-80 km NNW of the nearest village Саранпауль/Saranpaul as the crow flies, just above the tree line, at 64.9421°N, 60.3482°E, I came upon a construct of which I could not identify the purpose, historical or present:

[image: Photo of a rectangular arch in Ural mountains]

What is the purpose of this construct?  It was a little bit over 2 metre high.  It may be the remains of a previously larger construction, as I saw some beams lying on the ground.

Close-up photo:

[image: close-up of "gallows"]

Can anyone shed light on what this is for?

Comment: A portal to hell?

Comment: Maybe an observation tower? hunting tower?

Comment: @EarlGrey Doesn't look like either to me.

Comment: https://www.istockphoto.com/it/foto/persico-di-legno-gm1189103670-336552138 check the one on the right

Comment: @EarlGrey Maybe it's the remains of an old hunting stand in a style I don't recognise, but with the location it seems unlikely.  Hunter can just sit on the hillside a little higher.

Answer (score 5):

Ancient electric poles ?

There seems to be some doohickey on the top of the horizontal beam that would hold the lines.

Comment: The problem with this theory is that there is nothing anywhere near.  No habitation and no other similar constructs or visible remnants thereof.

Comment: I have made a simple search https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1&client=firefox-b-d&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=pKQmHZ7gfsBjmM%252Cz9s2pP8y75no1M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTmmhEbq3uICyF_84uq79jyirJakQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF6-6Yn7jqAhXJDuwKHS0ZBkQQ9QEwA3oECBkQIg&biw=1920&bih=938#imgrc=iMM47uaHVpYBPM

Comment: It does resemble a bit, but the logs are not straight - so I do not think those are the actual telegraph poles